# Django : unique=True constraint does not get removed using django migrations

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, django-migrations

I have a model as :

```
class order(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
```

I've migrated this model using django migrations (PostgreSql).

Now I wish to remove the unique constraint.

```
class order(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

On running `makemigrations`,
only an AlterField migration is created :

```
migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='order',
            name='serial',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=20),
        ),
```

On migrating this, the unique constraint is not removed. (it's visible in pgAdmin).

After this, I tried removing the constraint manually. The unique constraint name as in pgAdmin is 'order_serial_key'. In the migrations file, I added :

```
migrations.RemoveConstraint(
            model_name='order',
            name='order_serial_key'
        )
```

On migrating, it shows `ValueError: No constraint named order_serial_key on model order`

How can I remove this constraint using migrations ?

Comment: if you dont care about the data stored, just comment out the `serial` make and run migrations (it will delete the whole field) then add it again without the `unique=True`. I know its not *the* answer but during developement it saves a lot of time (debugging some bs db problems can be time-consuming)